# Sql query to calculate active count for aparticular date of every month

Tags: sqlite

I have data for the user regarding his subscription transaction date.

suppose if the user has a monthly subscription and the subscription date in on 4th of every month.
Then how can I count that user as an active user for 4th of every month

Data Available: 
[image: Data Regading user auto debit subscription date]

Data Required:
[image: On Every Subscription date that user should be count as active user.]

Since subscription begins from October.

Comment: Suggestion: **Always** store dates and times as one of the formats supported by [sqlite date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). It'll make working with them so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following will do what you wish :-

```
WITH potential_dates(d) AS 
    (
        SELECT date('2019-10-01' /* Start date */)
        UNION ALL 
            SELECT date(d,'+1 days') 
            FROM potential_dates 
            WHERE d < '2020-01-01' /* End date */
            LIMIT 1000 /* secondary/fail safe end of recursion */
    )
SELECT 
    subscriptiondate||strftime('/%m/%Y',d) AS Date, 
    count() AS userCount 
FROM potential_dates 
    JOIN subscription ON subscriptiondate = 0 + substr(d,9)
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY d
;
```

based upon the given data, the above results in :-

[image]

If there data were :-

[image]

Then the result would be :-

[image]